# error runnig android app through signingReport

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9T2B.png)

I'm trying for YouTube video player and Google Drive Api So I need SHI so click on singInReport
but it show error like

Comment: Have you googled the question title / your error message?

Comment: yes see the image plzz.. help

Answer (score 0):

Use the same version of java as the sources were compiled with or newer.